# How to hide a particular content of a web page if the size of screen is smaller?

Tags: forms

I want to hide a particular content of a web page if the size of the screen becomes smaller than 480px.

I know I should use this:

```
media screen and max-width : 360px
form     {     display     :      none ! important    ;    
}
```

But I also want to show a message when size becomes less than 480px:

> Please log in with your PC

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you want to hide something, show something, or both?

Comment: both @Jeffrey
i want to hide the login form and show the message"please log in with your PC" when the size of the screen becomes smaller than 480px

Comment: You can put your message in span or div with display none by default and when size becomes greater than 480 px make that div visible.

Comment: @Dipen_a thanks! 
but how to display a hidden style?
display:show; ????

Comment: .myDiv {
    display: block;
}

Comment: @Dipen_a: put those in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your message in span or div with display none by default and when size becomes greater than 480 px make that div visible as below

```
#myDiv {
    display: block;
 }
```